# Outlook checkmarks on emails not synching over workstations

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I am absolutely no Windows-administrator but I got asked for help in a small business here. There's an Exchange server running and Outlook on the workstations is pulling the emails there all from the same account. The Exchange server would pull the emails from the regular email server, checks for viruses and the local Outlook instances get the emails from there.

Recently the users started to complain that the checkmarks are not syncing. They use this to mark if an email was processed by an employee. The employee would put the green checkmark to an email and everyone in the office would see that this email was worked on.

Now I am completely lost, I tried to remove the accounts in Outlook and create them again on the local workstations but the problem persists. What could I do to further investigate the issue?

Comment: First thing, login to webmail `https://exchangeserver/owa` and see if the checkmarks sync there. This tells you where the checkmarks fail. If they are in owa, then other clients are not syncing. If they're not, its that client. Try it in reverse too. Let others check and see if that ends up in owa and also check from owa and see if that syncs. Once the problem is sufficiently narrowed down, research the remaining.

Comment: Try switching outlook to online mode check if the checkmarks can by synced.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching outlook to online mode check if the checkmarks can by synced.

Here's also a document about the sync issue for your reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/synchronization/synchronization-issues-occur-in-outlook-owa

Comment: Any update on this thread?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Outlook is online the whole time but still the checkmarks are not synchronized